# html inside link_to rails is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I´m new with ruby and I´m trying to insert an awesome-font icon inside a link using rails 3.2.15

This is my code

```
<%= link_to tweet_path(tweet), method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' do %>
    <i class="icon-trash"></i>
<% end %>

<%= link_to edit_tweet_path(tweet) do %>
     <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
<% end %>
```

I don´t know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<%= link_to raw('<i class="icon-trash"></i>'), tweet_path(tweet), method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:i,nil, :class => "icon-trash"), tweet_path(tweet), method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>

<%= link_to content_tag(:i,nil, :class => "icon-pencil"), edit_tweet_path(tweet) %>
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you. I had already done it. FYI there's a gem for that. :)